# How to write a string without double quotes to a sink in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a .txt file which has json structured data, I have to read the data and load it into a json file, but while writing it consideres the source as a string and adds double quotes and escape characters to the json data. I do not want this, I want the original Json data to be written to the sink json file.

And I want to accomplish this in Azure Data Flow, do help.

Comment: Have you tried using the parse formatter in a data flow?

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, by default, it will add the `backslash(\)` for strings as an escape character for `double quotes (")`. That is the reason for adding double quotes and escape characters to the JSON data. To remove those, you can follow the procedure below:

Take the JSON in the Lookup activity, as shown below:

[image]

Take the Set Variable activity and create an **array** variable with the name `sa`. Convert it into JSON format using the expression below.

```py
@json(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.StoreGroupMembers)
```

You will get it in JSON format, as shown below:

[image]

Here is my pipeline JSON for your reference:

```json
{
    "name": "json",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "sa",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@json(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.StoreGroupMembers)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "sa": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```